# Intersection of lists

Tags: c#, ruby, list, intersection

Is there a better, more elegant and concise, way to get the intersection of two lists in C#?

In C# a method to calculate an intersection of list of dates is:

```
    public List<DateTime> dates_common(Timeserie ts1, Timeserie ts2)
    {
        var dt1 = new HashSet<DateTime>(ts1.dates);
        var dt2 = new HashSet<DateTime>(ts2.dates);
        dt1.IntersectWith(dt2);
        var dt = new DateTime[dt1.Count];
        dt1.CopyTo(dt);
        return new List<DateTime>(dt);
    }
```

In Ruby one would do this as:

```
def dates_common(ts1, ts2)
    dt1 = ts1.dates.to_set    
    dt2 = ts2.dates.to_set
    return dt1.intersection(dt2).to_a
end
```

The root cause of this clunkiness is the asymmetry between IEnumerable and concrete containers and arrays.

I am constantly amazed how badly designed C# standard libraries are as this kind of problems come up all the time.

Is there a better, this means more elegant and concise, way to do this?

Comment: The fact that you don't know how to use them properly doesn't mean that the standard libraries are badly designed... IMHO they are, on the contrary, very well designed (well, most of them are). BTW, the solution proposed by dtb is almost exactly the same as your Ruby solution.

Comment: Take 10 minutes and learn the basics of LINQ, you will quickly find that the .Net collection library is very rich. When I write code in other languages I often find myself writing LINQ methods.

Comment: Are there any reasons for not using LINQ extensively? Under which conditions that would be the case?

Comment: I can't see any reason except having to maintain legacy, pre-.net3.5, code. And in some cases a solution with linq is hard to make as performant as one with classic constructs, but I've found those to be very rare. So, just take the best from wherever you can get it, it may change your name into "istilldontlikemsbutsometimesitisnottoobadactually" ;).

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) and [Enumerable.ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) as follows to get very elegant and concise code:

```
public List<DateTime> dates_common(Timeserie ts1, Timeserie ts2)
{
    return ts1.dates.Intersect(ts2.dates).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I was aware of this but it requires using System.Linq;

Comment: System.Linq is a part of .Net framework starting from 3.5 version

Comment: excluding linq is saying, "why isn't there a better way to do this other than the better way to do this?"

Answer (score 1):

```
    // This function is used to remove those alias from 'cc' which are common in 'to' and 'cc' list.

    private static void RemoveCommonFromCc(ref List<string> to, ref List<string> cc)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> common = (List<string>)to.Intersect(cc);
        foreach(var removeCc in common)
        {
            cc.Remove(removeCc);
        }
    }
```